# xCode swift Storyboard Single view controller with multiple/dynamic views inside

Tags: xcode, swift, storyboard, view

Im fairly new to xCode and Im wondering what would be the logic (using storyboard) to create a view composed of two distinct views:

```
View1 : 100%width - 70%height

View2 : 100%width - 30%height
```

By swiping up/down, user could expand View2 from 30% height to 70% height (reducing height of View1 from 70% to 30%)

Im sorry if that's not a lot of information but I didn't manage to find any solution / good information to learn from.

Any help would be great!
Thanks

Comment: Constraints should help you with 30% and 70% height thing. As for for expanding maybe look into adjusting each views frame and constraints when swiped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag and drop 2 `UIView` objects from View hierarchy. They should be child of `UIView` of `ViewController`.

Then from attribute inspector you can change values as per your need.

Comment: Ok so if I well understood the process of parenting, I need to insert a UIView container inside my viewController, and then add to extra UIView inside the existing UIView ?

viewController(UIView(UIView, UIView)) ?

Comment: I didn't have time to review this but I will in to coming day and validate the answer if that does the trick ;) thanks!